# When to use byte array & when byte buffer?

Tags: java, byte, arrays, buffer

What is the difference between a byte array & byte buffer ?
  **Also, in what situations should one be preferred over the other?**

[my usecase is for a web application being developed in java].

Answer (score 96):

There are actually a number of ways to work with bytes. And I agree that it's not always easy to pick the best one:

- the `byte[]`
- the `java.nio.ByteBuffer`
- the `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream` (in combination with other streams)
- the `java.util.BitSet`

The `byte[]` is just a primitive array, just containing the raw data. So, it does not have convenient methods for building or manipulating the content.

**A `ByteBuffer` is more like a builder.** It creates a `byte[]`. Unlike arrays, it has more convenient helper methods. (e.g. the `append(byte)` method). It's not that straightforward in terms of [usage](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/buffers.html). *(Most tutorials are way too complicated or of poor quality, but this [one](https://www.novixys.com/blog/java-nio-using-bytebuffer/) will get you somewhere. Take it one step further? then read about the many [pitfalls](https://worldmodscode.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/the-java-bytebuffer-a-crash-course/).)*

You could be tempted to say that a `ByteBuffer` does to `byte[]`, what a `StringBuilder` does for `String`. But there is a specific difference/shortcoming of the `ByteBuffer` class. Although it may appear that a bytebuffer resizes automatically while you add elements, **the `ByteBuffer` actually has a fixed capacity.** When you instantiate it, you already have to specify the **maximum size** of the buffer.

That's one of the reasons, why **I often prefer to use the `ByteArrayOutputStream` because it automatically resizes,** just like an `ArrayList` does. (It has a `toByteArray()` method). Sometimes **it's practical, to wrap it in a `DataOutputStream`.** The advantage is that you will have some additional convenience calls, (e.g. `writeShort(int)` if you need to write 2 bytes.)

**`BitSet` comes in handy when you want to perform bit-level operations.** You can get/set individual bits, and it has logical operator methods like `xor()`. (The `toByteArray()` method was only introduced in java 7.)

Of course depending on your needs you can combine all of them to build your `byte[]`.

Comment: your answer is very helpful

Comment: It is categorically wrong to say ByteBuffer to byte[] is like StringBuilder to String. No it is not. ByteBuffer to byte[] is more like FancyString to String. It does NOT have the builder capability StringBuilder offer. As you mentioned, it is fixed-size and no way to grow it. The true reasons for why we need ByteBuffer are two fold: 1) Direct memory access. This means when used in direct mode, ByteBuffer can bypass the JVM garbage collection, and the memory used by ByteBuffer is completely outside the JVM memory pool. 2) Interfacing, as byte[] is primitive and cannot be used in OO way.

Answer (score 28):

ByteBuffer is part of the new IO package (nio) that was developed for fast throughput of file-based data. Specifically, Apache is a very fast web server (written in C) because it reads bytes from disk and puts them on the network directly, without shuffling them through various buffers. It does this through memory-mapped files, which early versions of Java did not have. With the advent of nio, it became possible to write a web server in java that is as fast as Apache. When you want very fast file-to-network throughput, then you want to use memory mapped files and ByteBuffer.

Databases typically use memory-mapped files, but this type of usage is seldom efficient in Java. In C/C++, it's possible to load up a large chunk of memory and cast it to the typed data you want. Due to Java's security model, this isn't generally feasible, because you can only convert to certain native types, and these conversions aren't very efficient. ByteBuffer works best when you are just dealing with bytes as plain byte data -- once you need to convert them to objects, the other java io classes typically perform better and are easier to use.

If you're not dealing with memory mapped files, then you don't really need to bother with ByteBuffer -- you'd normally use arrays of byte. If you're trying to build a web server, with the fastest possible throughput of file-based raw byte data, then ByteBuffer (specifically MappedByteBuffer) is your best friend.

Comment: It is not the Java security model that is the limitation.  It is the JVM architecture that prevents you from casting bytes to typed data.

Comment: The security model also affects the usability of ByteBuffer -- at least in my testing which is a few years old now. Every time you call one of the cast functions in the ByteBuffer class, SecurityManager code gets executed, which slows the whole process down. This is why regular java io functions are generally faster for reading in java basic types. This contrasts with C, where memory mapped files with a cast are much, much faster than using stdio.

Comment: Looking at the code, the security manager calls only appear to occur in DirectByteBuffer case.  I think it happens because the method is using `Unsafe`.

Answer (score 3):

Those two articles may help you http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly and http://evanjones.ca/software/java-bytebuffers.html

Comment: I can not reproduce the first link's conclusion that FileChannel is relevantly faster than FileInputStream for reading into byte[]. I suspect that since they use a file of length 100MB, they actually benchmark reading from the operating system's disk cache rather than the hard drive itself. That would explain why their tests imply a bandwith of 250MB/s, which is pretty damn fast for a disk. In my tests with a 1.5GB file, both methods achieve a throughput of 40MB/s, indicating that the disk is the bottleneck, not the CPU. Of course, mileage with a solid state disk might differ.

Comment: You could improve the quality of this answer by letting us know why these links might be helpful.  Link-only answers are not ideal.