# Convert Integer to Hex-> LittleEndian format in Java

Tags: java, hex, byte, endianness

I am trying to get the Little Endian format value in Hex(in Java) for my code but getting fffff in the first digit and not getting the value similar to what this site returns: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html

Here is the code:

```
private static void convertToHex() {

    String hextestValue = Integer.toHexString(1234);
    int value = Integer.parseInt(hextestValue, 16);
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    bb.putInt(value);
    System.out.print("x = ");
    for (byte b : bb.array()) {
        System.out.printf("%2s", Integer.toHexString(b) + " ");
    }

}
```

Not sure what needs to be done to return the result in similar format.

e.g. for input 1234 I need the output: D2   04

Comment: A `byte` is a signed integer between -128 and 127, when it is promoted to an int it is sign-extended. `Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff)` should accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thank you this worked. Is it possible to convert the overall array to HexString rather than looping through each byte and converting it to Hex?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.printf("%02X ", b);`

Is what you need

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer of @g00se,

It may also be worth noting that an `int` consumes 4 bytes in java.
For that reason you are forced to allocate 4 bytes in your example.

However, a `short` is only 2 bytes.

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
bb.putShort((short)value);
```

That will get rid of the unnecessary bytes.

Comment: I didn't want to go too far off-topic. But a long time ago, I wrote a summary of different byte manipulation tools here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210840/when-to-use-byte-array-when-byte-buffer/32045701#32045701